# How to implement kitchen sink's twitter window

Tags: twitter, titanium, sink

I'm very new to Titanium developer and i'm building an app in which I'm trying to implement Kitchen Sink's Twitter window, I already figured out that you can easily change the username from which it picks up the tweets, but I can't seem to get that window into my own app. What files do I have to copy/paste or what parts of the code do I have to use?
Thanks!